# recognising humanoid arm

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to make a system that can recognize poses that are attained by a humanoid robotic arm; like that of asimo.

I am currently looking into the libraries that detect real human poses like openpose, as the visual similarity is of a high degree between the arms.

I was wondering if I could retrain a model that already recognizes human arms.